# Turn on Unicode text support in Hive queries

Tags: hadoop, unicode, hive, hue

I have 2 Hadoop clusters with Hive. The first version has Hive 1.2.1.2.3.0.0-2557. A simple query with unicode works just fine:

```
select 'Привет', '你好'
```

The second has version Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169. Same query gives this error:

```
Error occurred executing hive query: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9F\xD1\x80\xD0\xB8...' for column 'query' at row 1
```

Is there a setting for Unicode support in Hive queries? How do I turn it on?

Comment: Figured is not a Hive problem but Hue, where i run queries. Seems need to configure Hue for unicode string support. Any idea where it might be?

Comment: This works though in Hue 3.11: http://demo.gethue.com/notebook/editor?editor=107739